# Laravel: How to save checkbox value

Tags: laravel, checkbox

I get this error, when I submit the form

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'onloan' cannot be null

Please help. Sorry for the noob question. I've been searching but the examples are different.

edit.blade.php

```php
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="checkbox" class="" id="onloan" value="1" {{ $item->onloan == 1 ? 'checked' : '' }}>
  <label for="onloan">On Loan</label>
</div>
```

controller

```php
    public function update(Request $request, Item $item)
    {
        $item->update([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'description' => $request->description,
            'barcode' => $request->barcode,
            'onloan' => $request->onloan //Not Working
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: add `name="onloan"` on your input field, otherwise it wont pass data with form submit method. `<input type="checkbox"  class="" name="onloan" id="onloan" value="1" {{ $item->onloan == 1 ? 'checked' : '' }}>` then from your controller `'onloan' => ($request->onloan) ? '1' : '0';`

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate it. Sorry my level is too low. I cannot upvote your comment. If you put it in the answer, I can checkmark it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `name="onloan"` on your input field, otherwise it won't pass data with form submit method.

```
<input type="checkbox"  class="" name="onloan" id="onloan" value="1" {{ $item->onloan == 1 ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```

If you uncheck the checkbox, then it will send nothing with submit, so from your controller you can give a value (`0`) if value is not passed :

```
'onloan' => ($request->onloan) ? '1' : '0';
```

Or,

```
if(isset($request->onloan)) {
  $onloan = "1";
} else {
  $onloan = "0";
}

'onloan' => $onloan,
```

Comment: Ah. Thank you very much for explaining it. I've been figuring out how it works. This is great!